# Is there a library of sound effects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, meteor

I'm just looking for a relatively large Javascript object where key/value pairs would be string/audiofile, such that key 'lion' would give me value 'roar.mp3'?  I looked at http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/demo/ but aside from the few demo sounds, I didn't see much else.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
[`howler.js`](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library)

The are pretty good...

Comment: Excellent resource find